# One channel entry per category

Tags: expressionengine

Does anyone know a way to show one entry per category in a channel:entries tag or a custom query? This has to be dynamic to show only the latest entry from each category, and not all entries have categories. For example, if in a list of entries two or more had the same category assigned only the latest would be shown.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Easy: list your categories, and within each category, grab one entry from it. Be wary if you have lots of categories, as the number of queries could get out of hand:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="my_channel" show_empty="no" cache="yes" refresh="60"}
    <h2>{category_name}</h2>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" limit="1" category="{category_id}" disable="categories|pagination" cache="yes" refresh="60"}
    <p>{title}</p>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Note that in this example, if an entry had several categories assigned to it, and that entry was also the newest entry for each of those categories, it *would* show up under each heading.

Comment: Thanks Derek. Not all entries have categories assigned though. I think I’ll just have to force that.

Comment: But if an entry isn't categorized, you don't want to show it, correct?

Comment: No, I do need to show entries without categories too. It’s a rare case I know but some entries need grouping and only the latest shown.

Comment: You'll probably want to write a custom function in an add-on in that case. Many queries and counting involved methinks.

Comment: Agreed, I think an add-on is the only answer without forcing categories. Thanks for taking a look.